# Postgres Query Return 0 If Empty For Date

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

I did some digging within stackoverflow for a solution and nothing quite matched what I was after (I don't think).

My goal is to combine two queries that will return 3 columns [date, **OUT**, **IN**] as output.
On their own, the two queries return the correct output.

1st SELECT query for **OUT** returns
[03/01, 4],[03/02, 10],[03/03, 21],[03/01, 4]

2nd SELECT query for **IN** returns
[03/01, 4],[03/03, 25]

Using WITH to combine the two queries, two different ways, the outputs are identical.

[03/01, 4, 4], [03/03, 21, 25] -> **OUT** as inner query

[03/01, 4, 4], [03/03, 21, 25] -> **IN** as inner query

As can be seen, because nothing came **IN** on the 2nd and 4th of March, an empty row is returned for those dates. I believe the correct way to use the WITH query is to have the **OUT** as the inner query so the 2nd and 4th are part of the recursion in the outer query.

Pasted below is a simplified version of what the WITH query looks like. On its own, the inner query returns a count for each day of March. For some reason, the outer query does not return 0 when it does not have a count for the date in question (2nd and 4th).
Anyone have advice on how to solve this one? Could I be using COALESCE incorrectly?

```
 WITH first_query (the_date, out) AS
 (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON(to_char(t1.date, 'dd')) to_char(t1.out_date, 'dd') AS out_date2, count(to_char(t1.out_date, 'dd')) AS out
    FROM table_out AS t1
    WHERE to_char(t1.out_date,'yyyy') = to_char(date_trunc('year', CURRENT_DATE), 'YYYY')  
    AND to_char(t1.out_date,'MM') = to_char(date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE), 'MM')  
    AND t1.out_id = 14
    GROUP BY out_date2

 )
SELECT fq.the_date AS day_of_month, fq.out, COALESCE( ( SELECT COUNT(to_char(t1.in_date, 'DD')) ), 0) AS in
FROM first_query fq, table_in t1
WHERE to_char(t1.in_date,'yyyy') = to_char(date_trunc('year', CURRENT_DATE), 'YYYY') 
AND to_char(t1.in_date,'MM') = to_char(date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE), 'MM')
AND to_char(t1.in_date,'dd') = fq.the_date
GROUP BY day_of_month, fq.out
ORDER BY day_of_month ASC
```

The answer ended up requiring CAST and LEFT JOIN as Jeremy suggested. The timestamps made this harder than it had to be.

```
    SELECT CAST(t1.out_date AS Date) AS date2, count(DISTINCT 
    t1.id) out, count(DISTINCT t2.id) AS in
    FROM table_out as t1
    LEFT JOIN table_in AS t2 ON CAST(t1.out_date AS Date) =         
    CAST(t2.in_date AS Date)
    WHERE to_char(t1.out_date,'yyyy') = 
    to_char(date_trunc('year',         CURRENT_DATE), 'YYYY')
    AND to_char(t1.out_date,'MM') = to_char(date_trunc('month',                         
    CURRENT_DATE), 'MM')
    AND t1.out_id = 14
    GROUP BY out_date2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I believe your issue is using a cross join between fq and t1 and then adding a where condition, which removes the rows that don't match.  You should instead use a LEFT OUTER JOIN or maybe a FULL OUTER JOIN and include the condition in the join: `FROM first_query fq LEFT OUTER JOIN table_in t1 ON (to_char(t1.in_date,'dd') = fq.the_date)`.  However, this query is confusing overall.  I don't really understand why you are combining DISTINCT ON and GROUP BY in first_query.

Comment: Thank you for replying Jeremy. I have continued to play with the query and have been able to simplify it by removing DISTINCT ON. Good catch! 
I have tried using LEFT OUTER JOIN and FULL OUTER JOIN. What happens now is if both IN and OUT return a non-zero integer there is something recursive happening because the numbers are multiplied. 
What is now returned is [03/01, 16, 16], [03/02, 10, 0], [03/03, 525, 525], [03/04, 4, 0]     
OUT on its own is [03/01, 4], [03/02, 10], [03/03, 21],[03/04, 4]
IN on its own is [03/01, 4], [03/03, 25]

Answer (score 0):

The answer ended up requiring CAST and LEFT JOIN as Jeremy suggested. The timestamps made this harder than it had to be.

```
SELECT CAST(t1.out_date AS Date) AS date2, count(DISTINCT 
t1.id) out, count(DISTINCT t2.id) AS in
FROM table_out as t1
LEFT JOIN table_in AS t2 ON CAST(t1.out_date AS Date) =         
CAST(t2.in_date AS Date)
WHERE to_char(t1.out_date,'yyyy') = 
to_char(date_trunc('year',         CURRENT_DATE), 'YYYY')
AND to_char(t1.out_date,'MM') = to_char(date_trunc('month',                         
CURRENT_DATE), 'MM')
AND t1.out_id = 14
GROUP BY out_date2
```